# Which Zend 2.2 resource plugin to choose?

Tags: php, mysql, database, plugins, zend-framework2

I am interested in learning Zend Framework 2.2. It's my first time I use Zend and I hit into some decision problems.

I have successfully completed the provied Album-tutorial from the documentation pages. In there the Zend/Db/TableGateway plugin is used. I did notice that there are many other plugins available though, but I don't know which is the most fitting for my purposes.

For what I understand from the documentations they all can do about the same things in general but have some different approches.

I have tried to check the internet (google, etc) but could not find any comparison or suggestions what to use.

What I would like to do is :

1. Basic db-access (create, select, delete, etc) on a mysql-database.
2. Implement user-specific rights for the database access (not every user should be allowed to access all data).
3. Selecting with more complex restrictions and complex ordering. In the past I had code creating long SQL queries by connecting various strings together and calling php's mysqli_query()/etc. I would like to have support when creating more complex queries (many WHERE directives, complex ORDER BY rules, mysql-if's, custom select-fields, etc).

Which of the available Zend Framework 2.2 database/resource-plugins are able to support implementation of my requirements?

Comment: I believe my question fits the rules now. Please reopen it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our current project we use:

```
 "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": ">=0.8.0",
 "zf-commons/zfc-user": ">=0.1.2",
 "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": ">=0.1.1",
 "manuakasam/sam-user": "dev-master",
 "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": ">=1.4.0",
 "zf-commons/zfc-admin": ">=0.1.1",
```

While the doctrine ORM handels all of our business logic we use the ACL providing from bjy-authorize to "limit" the access of controllers and/or actions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you do not use the zf plugins and decided to replace them with doctrine and bjy plugins? What was the reason for that? Are the zf-plugins not able or too limited to achieve the requirements?

Comment: They save programming time.